# How does magento calculate tax with coupons?

Tags: price, tax, bug

I know there is a bug in magento about tax. I'm not looking into solving that. I just want to understand **how** it calculates and why it fails to do the calculation correctly so that I can replicate it in my module and get the prices match.

```
Row Total $39.75

Subtotal    $45.00
Shipping & Handling $7.95
Discount (10percent)    -$4.50
Tax $8.08
Grand Total $48.44
Total Paid  $48.44
```

When in fact it should be 48.45

Thanks!